# AWS Custom Windows AMI - How to deal with Updates?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-ami, windows-server-2012-r2

I'm toying with AWS at the moment, with the intention of having an autoscaling windows system. I have a script that will grab the latest code from a GIT Repo - however I was wondering how people deal with Windows Updates, because surely the AMI is going to have to be updated on a regular basis with the latest Windows Updates (is this correct?) So I was curious how people go about upgrading windows, and creating a new AMI and how often?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

How often you accept Windows Updates and with how much testing thereafter is a question to consider carefully with respect to your server's exposure and criticalness. Your estimation of the risk of performing a Windows Update is considerable too.

You don't *have* to pre-bake AMI's with the latest updates of software, including system (OS) software.  Here is a method well explained of [Using a PowerShell Module to Run Windows Update](http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2012/11/08/use-a-powershell-module-to-run-windows-update.aspx).

Comment: Hi, I did think about a upgrade script, but when you consider that it has to run on demand during a period of high load, and that Windows likes to reboot after quite a few updates it seems, I don't know if this would be ideal or practical. It's almost as of you could do with an instance that gets updated once a week and then somehow automatically updates the AMI?

Comment: I use pre-baked AMIs on systems I auto-scale.  I _could_ use a base AMI for demand autoscaling, if it is for a very limited/restricted specific tasks.

Comment: How often do you bake your AMI's?

Comment: No set rule - when practical.  For example, servers with very limited function, that are tightly secured, need not be updated as often as servers open to the public on port 80.  Some would condemn this, but doing it all on "Patch Tuesday" isn't practical.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Systems Manager RunCommand feature with the `AWS-InstallWindowsUpdates` document. This loop doesn't complete until all the windows updates have been downloaded, installed, rebooted and checked again. See log below for the kind of actions it encompasses

```
$InstanceId=?????
$runPSCommand=Send-SSMCommand -InstanceId @($instanceid) -DocumentName AWS-InstallWindowsUpdates -Comment 'Run Windows Updates whilst baking an AMI' -Parameter @{'Action'='Install'}

Write-Host "Waiting for Windows Updates to complete..."
do {
   Sleep -Seconds 10
   $CmdStatus = Get-SSMCommandInvocation -InstanceId $instanceid -CommandId $runPSCommand.CommandId
} Until ($CmdStatus.Status -eq "Success")
Write-Host "Windows Updates complete"
```

And this is some sample output showing the reboot and recheck if there are more updates to install

```
04/10/2017 06:24:51 UTC | Info | Start of Install-AwsUwiWindowsUpdates
04/10/2017 06:24:51 UTC | Info | Searching for Windows Updates.
04/10/2017 06:27:10 UTC | Info | Found 4 available Windows Updates.
04/10/2017 06:27:10 UTC | Info | Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB3052480)
04/10/2017 06:27:10 UTC | Info | Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2, 2016 x64 Edition - March 2017 (KB890830)
04/10/2017 06:27:10 UTC | Info | March, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB4012216)
04/10/2017 06:27:10 UTC | Info | March, 2017 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB4012219)
04/10/2017 06:27:10 UTC | Info | Downloading Windows Updates.
04/10/2017 06:27:35 UTC | Info | Successfully Downloaded: Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB3052480)
04/10/2017 06:27:36 UTC | Info | Successfully Downloaded: Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2, 2016 x64 Edition - March 2017 (KB890830)
04/10/2017 06:28:32 UTC | Info | Successfully Downloaded: March, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB4012216)
04/10/2017 06:29:34 UTC | Info | Successfully Downloaded: March, 2017 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB4012219)
04/10/2017 06:29:34 UTC | Info | 4 Windows Updates will be installed.
04/10/2017 06:29:34 UTC | Info | Installed: Update for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB3052480)
04/10/2017 06:30:15 UTC | Info | Installed: Windows Malicious Software Removal Tool for Windows 8, 8.1, 10 and Windows Server 2012, 2012 R2, 2016 x64 Edition - March 2017 (KB890830)
04/10/2017 06:30:29 UTC | Info | Installed: March, 2017 Security Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB4012216)
04/10/2017 06:30:44 UTC | Info | Installed: March, 2017 Preview of Monthly Quality Rollup for Windows Server 2012 R2 (KB4012219)
04/10/2017 06:30:44 UTC | Info | Windows requires a reboot.  Sending reboot request to SSM Agent.
04/10/2017 06:33:44 UTC | Info | Start of Install-AwsUwiWindowsUpdates
04/10/2017 06:33:44 UTC | Info | Searching for Windows Updates.
04/10/2017 06:36:29 UTC | Info | Found 0 available Windows Updates.
```

You can use this as part of a script to bake an AMI, or rebake an AMI.

You may also use -Target, instead of -InstanceId, and specify a filter with a tag to update all instances that match the filter.